# How to set NSDictionary in SingleTon class in swift language

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6, singleton

Am newbie to swift language. I want to store my login response from a dictionary in singleton class. Whenever i want that data, i want to reuse it from dictionary in singleton class. Please find my mistakes. Herewith i attached my sample code.

My SingleTon Class

```
class MarblesSingleton: NSObject { 
    class var sharedInstance:MarblesSingleton
    {
        struct Singleton
        {
            static let instance = MarblesSingleton()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }
    var provisionalDataDict:NSDictionary!
    override init() {        
        super.init()
        self.provisionalDataDict = nil
    } 
}
let singletonClass = MarblesSingleton()
```

After Login i added that response to dictionary in singleton class like this,

```
singletonClass.provisionalDataDict = jsonData
```

In another class, i want to use that data from singleton class like this,

```
m_CountryTextField.text = NSString(format: "%@", singletonClass.provisionalDataDict.valueForKey("country") as NSString)
```

My Issue is : i got crash with fatal error.

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

[image]

Comment: when you creates an instances of the class using `let singletonClass = MarblesSingleton()` you are not using the singleton pattern, instead you are creating a new object. Try using `let singletonClass = MarblesSingleton.sharedInstance` instead

Comment: You need to determine which thing is `nil`. Is it `singletonClass`? Is it `provisionalDataDict`? Is it the `valueForKey(..)` response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you should do what `tkanzakic` wrote to use the singleton. Then you have to check if your dictionary is valid:

```
if var unwrapped_Dic = singletonClass.provisionalDataDict {
   m_CountryTextField.text = unwrapped_Dic.valueForKey("country") as NSString
}
```

if you work with optionals, you always should check if the forced unwrapping was successful.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
class DataManager {

    struct Static {
        static var token : dispatch_once_t = 0
        static var instance : DataManager?
    }

    class var instance: DataManager {
        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {  Static.instance = DataManager() }
        return Static.instance!
    }

    init(){
        assert(Static.instance == nil, "Singleton already initialized!")
    }

var userId = "defaultId"
var password = "defaultPassword"

}
```

and later on you can just access them by DataManager.Instance.userId
or set to other value DataManager.Instance.userId = "newUserId"

you can also create a Dictionary variable inside the singleton class if you really want.

Hope that help!